# how to remove hashtag, @user, link of a tweet using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I need to preprocess tweets using Python. Now I am wondering what would be the regular expression to remove all the hashtags, @user and links of a tweet respectively?

for example,

1. `original tweet: @peter I really love that shirt at #Macy. http://bet.ly//WjdiW4`

   - processed tweet: `I really love that shirt at Macy`
2. original tweet: `@shawn Titanic tragedy could have been prevented Economic Times: Telegraph.co.ukTitanic tragedy could have been preve... http://bet.ly/tuN2wx`

   - processed tweet: `Titanic tragedy could have been prevented Economic Times Telegraph co ukTitanic tragedy could have been preve`
3. original tweet: `I am at Starbucks http://4sh.com/samqUI (7419 3rd ave, at 75th, Brooklyn)`

   - processed tweet: `I am at Starbucks 7419 3rd ave at 75th Brooklyn`

I just need the meaningful words in each Tweet. I don't need the username, or any links or any punctuations.

Comment: Note that the Twitter API can give you "[Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities)" which already have hashtags, usernames, and URLs parsed. This would make your job much easier if you can fetch the Tweets you're using via the API.

Comment: @MichaelMior You should have posted an example with the API. That's the best answer.

Comment: That's why I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: Well, then, if Peiti is going to use the API he should change his question to something along the lines of, "What's the best way to parse tweets?", to which the answer is "Use the existing API that does so."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following example is a close approximation. Unfortunately there is no right way to do it just via regular expression. The following regex just strips of an URL (not just http), any punctuations, User Names or Any non alphanumeric characters. It also separates the word with a single space. If you want to parse the tweet as you are intending you need more intelligence in the system. Some precognitive self learning algorithm considering there is no standard tweet feed format.

Here is what I am proposing.

```
' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
```

and here is the result on your examples

```
>>> x="@peter I really love that shirt at #Macy. http://bit.ly//WjdiW4"
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'I really love that shirt at Macy'
>>> x="@shawn Titanic tragedy could have been prevented Economic Times: Telegraph.co.ukTitanic tragedy could have been preve... http://bit.ly/tuN2wx"
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'Titanic tragedy could have been prevented Economic Times Telegraph co ukTitanic tragedy could have been preve'
>>> x="I am at Starbucks http://4sq.com/samqUI (7419 3rd ave, at 75th, Brooklyn) "
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'I am at Starbucks 7419 3rd ave at 75th Brooklyn'
>>>
```

and here are few examples where it is not perfect

```
>>> x="I c RT @iamFink: @SamanthaSpice that's my excited face and my regular face. The expression never changes."
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'I c RT that s my excited face and my regular face The expression never changes'
>>> x="RT @AstrologyForYou: #Gemini recharges through regular contact with people of like mind, and social involvement that allows expression of their ideas"
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'RT Gemini recharges through regular contact with people of like mind and social involvement that allows expression of their ideas'
>>> # Though after you add # to the regex expression filter, results become a bit better
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("([@#][A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'RT recharges through regular contact with people of like mind and social involvement that allows expression of their ideas'
>>> x="New comment by diego.bosca: Re: Re: wrong regular expression? http://t.co/4KOb94ua"
>>> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
'New comment by diego bosca Re Re wrong regular expression'
>>> #See how miserably it performed?
>>>
```

Comment: Twitter usernames can contain underscores in addition to A-Z, a-z and 0-9.

Comment: ```' '.join(re.sub("(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)|(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())```

use this instead to filter the hashtag too^

Answer (score 17):

A little bit late, but this solution prevent punctuation mistakes like #hashtag1,#hashtag2 (without spaces), and implementation is very simple

```
import re,string

def strip_links(text):
    link_regex    = re.compile('((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+([\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&](#!)?)*)', re.DOTALL)
    links         = re.findall(link_regex, text)
    for link in links:
        text = text.replace(link[0], ', ')    
    return text

def strip_all_entities(text):
    entity_prefixes = ['@','#']
    for separator in  string.punctuation:
        if separator not in entity_prefixes :
            text = text.replace(separator,' ')
    words = []
    for word in text.split():
        word = word.strip()
        if word:
            if word[0] not in entity_prefixes:
                words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(words)


tests = [
    "@peter I really love that shirt at #Macy. http://bet.ly//WjdiW4",
    "@shawn Titanic tragedy could have been prevented Economic Times: Telegraph.co.ukTitanic tragedy could have been preve... http://bet.ly/tuN2wx",
    "I am at Starbucks http://4sh.com/samqUI (7419 3rd ave, at 75th, Brooklyn)",
]
for t in tests:
    strip_all_entities(strip_links(t))


#'I really love that shirt at'
#'Titanic tragedy could have been prevented Economic Times Telegraph co ukTitanic tragedy could have been preve'
#'I am at Starbucks 7419 3rd ave at 75th Brooklyn'
```

Comment: However, it fails in removing RT (also you didnt added any thing for that in entity_prefixed. I tried to add RT and rt but it didnt worked. as word[0] looks for only first alphabet.

Comment: A new use case (remove RT) could be solved coding a new function `remove_rt` that search for '$RT' and replace for empty string.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>This will work with your examples. If you have links inside your tweets, it will fail, **miserably**.</strike>

```
result = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", subject)
```

**Edit:**

works with internal links too, as long as they are separated by a space.

Just go with the API. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It will also fail for cases such as "I don't understand http"

Comment: @FailedDev what if the link is inside a tweet? I remember there is a method of "re" called "findall" would that be useful?

Comment: @MichaelMior Fair enough. Now it won't. But I am sure it can fail somehow :)

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi you could match all the words if you wanted. But your questions implies that you want to remove everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a regex but:

```
>>>
>>> import urlparse
>>> string = '@peter I really love that shirt at #Macy. http://bit.ly//WjdiW#'
>>> new_string = ''
>>> for i in string.split():
...     s, n, p, pa, q, f = urlparse.urlparse(i)
...     if s and n:
...         pass
...     elif i[:1] == '@':
...         pass
...     elif i[:1] == '#':
...         new_string = new_string.strip() + ' ' + i[1:]
...     else:
...         new_string = new_string.strip() + ' ' + i
...
>>> new_string
'I really love that shirt at Macy.'
>>>
```