# How to write clean data to a file in python in tabulated format

Tags: python, regex, twitter

Issue: Remove the hyperlinks, numbers and signs like `^&*$ etc` from twitter text. The tweet file is in CSV tabulated format as shown below:

```
s.No.   username   tweetText

1.      @abc  This is a test #abc example.com
2.      @bcd  This is another test #bcd example.com
```

Being a novice at python, I search and string together the following code, thanks to a the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376691/how-to-remove-hashtag-user-link-of-a-tweet-using-regular-expression):

```
import re
fileName="path-to-file//tweetfile.csv"
fileout=open("Output.txt","w")
with open(fileName,'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().lower() # read the file and convert all text to lowercase
    clean_data=' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",data).split()) # regular expression to strip the html out of the text
fileout.write(clean_data+'\n') # write the cleaned data to a file
fileout.close()
myfile.close()
print "All done"
```

It does the data stripping, but the output file format is not as I desire. The output text file is in a single line like

`s.no username tweetText 1 abc` This is a cleaned tweet `2 bcd` This is another cleaned tweet `3 efg` This is yet another cleaned tweet

How can I fix this code to give me an output like given below:

```
s.No. username  tweetText

1  abc  This is a test

2  bcd  This is another test

3  efg  This is yet another test
```

I think something needs to be added in the regular expression code but I don't know what it could be. Any pointers or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: How do you want to come from `some text` to `This is a test`?

Comment: Thank you Carsten Hagemann for pointing out that anomaly. I have now corrected the example.

Comment: Try for every element in clean_data write the element + '\n' or read the file line by line and process it the same way by extracting clean_data from the line and if it is not empty writing clean_data + '\n' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the line, clean it, and write it out in one loop. You can also use the CSV module to help you build out your result file.

```
import csv
import re

exp = r"(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"

def cleaner(row):
   return [re.sub(exp, " ", item.lower()) for item in row]

with open('input.csv', 'r') as i, open('output.csv', 'wb') as o:
    reader = csv.reader(i, delimiter=',')  # Comma is the default
    writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')

    # Take the first row from the input file (the header)
    # and write it to the output file

    writer.writerow(next(reader))

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(cleaner(row))
```

The csv module knows correctly how to add separators between items; as long as you pass it a collection of items.

So, what the `cleaner` method does it take each item (column) in the row from the input file, apply the substitution to the lowercase version of the item; and then return back a list.

The rest of the code is simply opening the file, configuring the CSV module with the separators you want for the input and output files (in the example code, the separator for both files is a tab, but you can change the output separator).

Next, the first row of the input file is read and written out to the output file. No transformation is done on this row (which is why it is not in the loop).

Reading the row from the input file automatically puts the file pointer on the next row - so then we simply loop through the input rows (in reader), for each row apply the cleaner function - this will return a list - and then write that list back to the output file with `writer.writerow()`.

Comment: Replace `writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t')` with `writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')` - this is the delimiter the writer will use.

Comment: there is a problem with your code. When I execute it, writes to a csv file but the columns are not separated. So basically it just writes s.No username,tweetText to a single column each. The output is supposed to be multiple columns like 1,abc, test message. Even after I replaced writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t') to writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')

Comment: Are you sure the file you are reading from has tabs between columns and not spaces?

Comment: many thanks to you for your prompt answer. The file that I am reading is also in CSV format so I just replaced your code like reader = csv.reader(i, delimiter=',') and writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',') And it now gives me the desired output. Please, edit your original code so that I can mark it as +1 too. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

instead of applying the re.sub() and the .lower() expressions to the entire file at once try iterating over each line in the CSV file like this:

```
for line in myfile:
    line = line.lower()
    line = re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",line)
    fileout.write(line+'\n')
```

also when you use the `with <file> as myfile` expression there is no need to close it at the end of your program, this is done automatically when you use with

Comment: WOW, You are the man! Thank you, Graham for the explanation. It works just like as I desired. Now, how do I add a comma between each word? Example sno, username,tweetText.

Comment: depends, are the words delineated by tab? if they are just call something like 'line = re.sub('\t', ',\t', line)' which just replaces all tabs with comma then tab, if its just whitespace the same thing will work just replace the ''/t'' regex with a whitespace one

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:
`clean_data=' '.join(re.sub("[@\^&\*\$]|#\S+|\S+[a-z0-9]\.(com|net|org)"," ",data).split()) # regular expression to strip the html out of the text`

Explanation:

- `[@\^&\*\$]` matches on the characters, you want to replace
- `#\S+`matches on hash tags
- `\S+[a-z0-9]\.(com|net|org)` matches on domain names

If the URLs can't be identified by `https?`, you'll have to complete the list of potential TLDs.

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eE0aR8/3)

Comment: Carsten +1 to you for explaining to me the regex.