# How to remove the stranger word from text

Tags: python, preprocessor

I'm setting up a new project in sentiment analysis , and want to remove any stranger word,character,emails,or any names with @ ,or any ling space ,clean any noise from text

```
input text ="@maggieNYT KFC must be out chicken.  This guy itأ?آ?أ?آ?أ?آ?s losing his shit."
```

**or**

```
input text ="‰??Aye babe. Why is Pizza hut calling you at 10 PM?‰?? "
```

**or**

```
input text ="The team will be in @KingstonLibrary tomorrow from 2:30 - 5:30pm. Providingأ?آپ#HIVأ?آپ/ #STI tests &amp;أ?آپ#freeأ?آپcondoms, along with information &amp; advice onأ?آپ#PrEP #contraceptionأ?آپ&amp; otherأ?آپ#sexualhealthأ?آپissues.
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to do what you are asking using [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)**, through the `re` library in python. You can think of regular expressions as a sort of advanced find-and-replace function.

User [@Abijit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977038/abhijit) provides a regular expression that will do the task in question in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8377440/11639533).

> ...The following regex just strips of an URL (not just http), any punctuations, User Names or Any non alphanumeric characters. It also separates the word with a single space....
>
> Here is what I am proposing.
>
> ```py
> ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",x).split())
> ```

Testing this out on your sample strings, it appears to work in your case as well. Here is my code.

```py
import re  # Python regex library
original: str = input()
# This following line uses @Abijit's regex
cleaned: str = ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",original).split())
print(cleaned)
```

The output for each one is as follows:

- `KFC must be out chicken This guy it s losing his shit`
- `Aye babe Why is Pizza hut calling you at 10 PM`
- `The team will be in tomorrow from 2 30 5 30pm Providing HIV STI tests amp free condoms along with information amp advice on PrEP contraception amp other sexualhealth issues`