# Twitter data analysis

Tags: python, twitter, dataset, screen-scraping, analysis

I have a question for my Thesis project.
In order to do a sentiment analysis, I would like to eliminate all hashtags, but with this Python code I remove only the "#". I would like to remove also the word associated to "#".
Thanks everyone

df['text']=df['text'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(re.findall(r'\w+', x)))

Comment: Might be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376691/how-to-remove-hashtag-user-link-of-a-tweet-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the rest of the words after the hashtag to remain intact, try this:

```
import re
df['text']=df['text'].apply(lambda x:(re.sub("#([\S]+)",'',x)))
```

It will remove any word(s) after the # until the next whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the re.sub method. Something like that:

```
df["text"] = df["text"].apply (lambda x : re.sub (r"#.*\s", "", x))
```

In this way you replace everything that matches the pattern "#.*\s" (hashtag followed by any amount of characters followed by a space) with an empty string. You may need to tweak the regex a bit depending on your data.

Check the documentation about the re module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html