# How to remove a specific character and one word following that character from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I wish to remove '#' from a client string.

Assume the string is '#Freahlife I just ate an apple'

I wish to write a function and extract only 'I just ate an apple'

How can I achieve this by using python? Thank you!

Comment: You could take some inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38119388/10826013).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

```
import re
re.sub(r"#\w+\s?", "", "#Freahlife I just ate an apple")

Out[8]: 'I just ate an apple'
```

Comment: It’s unclear what the OP would want to do with eg `"blah#wobble"` … but you might want to consider leading white space as well (with a lookback assertion)

Comment: for "blah#wobble" I might want to keep only blah since people only put tweets hashtag after the #sign

Comment: @donkopotamus: Right. I just wanted OP to familiarize with re module. He can then work his way from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` function and `strip` to remove any whitespace:

```
'#Freahlife I just ate an apple'.replace('#Freahlife','').strip()
```

or in generic:

```
' '.join('#Freahlife I just ate an apple'.split(' ')[1:])
```

Comment: I think they are looking for something a bit more general: replace *any* word starting with `"#"` not just `"#Freahlife"`.

Comment: @Mark Oh I see. Added a generic solution as well

Answer (score 0):

If `#` is followed by `Freahlife` only, you can use `replace` function as mentioned by @anosha_rehan. But if the following word is unknown, you can use `split` function and put all the words in a list. Then, you can just loop and check if `#` is in the current word and has an index of 0 (making sure `#` is found at the start of the word). Then, remove that from the list and convert the list into a string.